# Disable or remove mintues dropdown from daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-daterangepicker

I want to disable future hours from daterangepicker, i've tried

"maxDate": moment().utc().startOf('hour'),

but this is disabling future dates only not hours.

Also, how can i disable minutes dropdown or just remove it daterangepicker as i want to keep only hours dropdown.

below is what i'm using.

```js
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    "showISOWeekNumbers": true,
    "timePicker": true,
    "showDropdowns": true,
    "timePicker24Hour": true,
    "autoUpdateInput": true,
    "format" : 'HH:00',
    "maxDate": moment().utc().startOf('hour'),
    "dateLimit" : {
        'days': 7
    },
    "maxSpan": {
            "days": 7
     },
    "locale": {
        "cancelLabel": 'Clear',
        "format": "DD/MM/YYYY @ HH:00",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Apply",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
        "fromLabel": "Start",
        "toLabel": "End",
        "weekLabel": "W",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Su",
            "Mo",
            "Tu",
            "We",
            "Th",
            "Fr",
            "Sa"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1
    },
    "linkedCalendars": true,
    "startDate": 1
});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="demo" name="datefilter" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i could able to default and fix the minute dropdown to 00 by adding in my js code

"timePickerIncrement" : 60,